# How to nest elements within %a tag?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, tags, haml

I would like to wrap an event div in a `%a` tag to make the whole clickable.

This block:

```
= link_to event_path(event.id) do
    .flipper
        .event-inner
            ...
```

Compiles to:

```
<div class="event-container flip-container" ontouchstart="this.classList.toggle('hover');">
    <a href="/events/21"></a>
    <div class="flipper">
        <a href="/events/21"></a>
            <div class="event-inner"><a href="/events/21"></a>            
                ...
```

How could I get a unique `%a` wrapping the whole?

Answer (score 2):

Watch out for indentation in HAML :

```
= link_to(event_path(event.id)) do 
  .flipper
    .event-inner
      your_code_here
```

Comment: Sorry, the indentation issue is just a copy past error (edited above). It must be something else.

Comment: How does look like the exact content you warp under `.flipper` and `.event-inner` classes ? Image , text , div ?

Comment: I have divs, images, a form, and a table.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that haml don't compile well nested blocks. Especially, I had helper blocks within .event-inner.

The solution I found is switching to [slim](http://slim-lang.com/) that manage this well. Furthermore, it seems to compile 2 times faster and it exists haml to slim converters.